# Arabic in File Name Causes Compressed (zipped) Folders Error

Tags: zip, i18n

How can I get files named with Arabic characters added to and extracted from a .zip file.

For example, under Windows XP, I get an error message that says "The compression cannot be performed becasue the file or directory...contains characters in its name that Compressed (zipped) Folders cannot store...

Comment: Which program are you using? I never had  problems with 7zip on XP (but I only used Arabic filenames once or twice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when zip/unzip uzing Windows Zip but the issue gone when using [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Comment: I'll accept this to give you the points. I doubt the question is still relevant 6 years and several versions of Windows later.

Comment: I had the same issue two weeks ago on Windows 7 with latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Windows, navigate to `Control Panel > Region and Language > Administrative` tab, click on "Change system locale" and change the "Current language for non-Unicode programs" as Arabic. That should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: That seems to work to get the file added to the archive. But once it's extracted, the file name isn't retained - it's garbage.